# If a prime number $p$ satisfies $\gcd(a,p−1) = 1$, then for every integer $b$ the congruence relation $x^a \equiv b \pmod{p}$ has a solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Can someone please help me prove the following statement:

If a prime number $p$ satisfies $\gcd(a,p−1) = 1$, then for every integer $b$ the congruence
relation $x^a \equiv b \pmod{p}$ has a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt primitive root $g\pmod p$

$\displaystyle a\cdot$ind$_gx\equiv$ind$_gb\pmod{p-1}$

Using [Linear congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) theorem ([Proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence)), as $\displaystyle d=(a,p-1)=1$ always divides ind$_gb,$ the number of solutions will be $d$

Comment: It is not without interest to note that there are cases in which  $a|{p-1}$ and $x^a=b$ could have solution for all $b$ excepting $b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S=\{1^a,2^a,\cdots,(p-1)^a,p^a\}$ is contained in $\mathbb F_p$ and can be equal or distinct of it. If $(a,p-1)=1$ then for $b=0$ in $\mathbb F_p$ we have
$p^a=0$ and $x^a=0$ has a solution. Let $b\ne0$. If $x^a=b$ has no solution, then $x^a=y^a$ for some distinct  elements of the group multiplicative $\mathbb F_p^*$ then $z^a=1$ where $z=x\cdot y^{-1}$. But this implies $a$ divides $p-1$ by FLT, contradiction.